# How to have cog listener called before cog command

Tags: discord.py

I have some code for a cog that looks something like this:

```py
class Example(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.counter = 0
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        print("Listener triggered")
        self.counter += 1

    @commands.group()
    async def first(self, ctx):
        if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
            await ctx.send("Invalid subcommand")

    @first.command()
    async def second(self, ctx):
        print("Command triggered")
        await ctx.send(f"Current counter: {self.counter}")
```

When I run this code and send a message to my bot, `second` gets called before `on_message`. I have some code in `second` that expects `on_message` to be executed first, but I can't figure out a good way to make this happen. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

check [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) event.

and I think you are trying to make a bot count the number of valid uses of command.  To do this, try:

```
def check(message):
  #here put ur condition for message is a valide command 
await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
```